# Command output to file, new lines at top

Tags: bash, lubuntu, scripts, solaris

I'm rewriting some 20+ year old Unix scripts and I want the output to go to the screen and a file. I know this is possible with `tee`. Is there a similar command that stacks new lines on top, at the beginning of a file? I'd like the file to be output in reverse chronological order.

The script output will redirect to a WWW folder. For remotely viewing the output, I want to F5 in a browser and have new lines at the top of the browser window.
I'll recycle the file (`cp log log_$(date '+%Y%m%d') && cp /dev/null log`) everyday to keep it from growing too large.

I was hoping `tee` had a complimentary utility like `cat` has with `tac`, but alas no luck.

Comment: but OP also wants "the output to go to the screen"

Comment: Cross site post http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188323/68757

Answer (score 0):

To print to STDOUT **and** insert newlines at the beginning of your log file you'll have to rewrite it completely each time that could be really memory consuming.

This is a perl command that should do what you need though:

```
oldscript.sh | perl -ne '$log=$_.`cat my_log.txt`; open(F, ">", "my_log.txt"); print F $log; print'
```

Juts change the path to `my_log.txt` for your needs.